# I can not add the weblogic server in netbeans v11

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic12c, netbeans-11

I have installed the Weblogic 12c server and I want to add it to a project in Netbeans 11. When I select "add server" from server instance, the Weblogic server option is not displayed
[image: server instance netbeans 11 image]

I expected to see the option as shown in the following link https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/wls_12c_netbeans_install/wls_12c_netbeans_install.html

[image: expected server intances option image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to connect the plugin for weblogic from netbeans version 8.2.
You must copy the plug-in files from the netbeans 8.2 directory to the netbeans 11 directory.
Files of a plug-in:

- ...\plugins\servers\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-weblogic9.jar
- ...\plugins\servers\enterprise\config\Modules\org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-weblogic9.xml
- ...\plugins\servers\enterprise\update_tracking\org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-weblogic9.xml
- ...\plugins\servers\enterprise\update_tracking\org-netbeans-modules-weblogic-common.xml

Checked on versions 11, 11.1, 11.2.

Update.
Second method

The plugin can be compiled from sources.
Plugin sources here:
https://github.com/apache/netbeans/tree/master/contrib/j2ee.weblogic9
But you need to build all netbeans project. Build command:

> ant all

The resulting .nbm file can then be imported in NetBeans (Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugin)

Discussion of the problem here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2476

Compiled nbm plugin file:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12991973/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-weblogic9.nbm

Checked on versions 12.x

Comment: Works also on 12.4

Comment: and also on 12.5

Comment: unfortunately - use the above at your own risk. in my case, although netbeans 12.3 could add the server, i wasn't able to make the debugging work properly - breakpoints were not hit - and each subsequent time i tried to run the Debug again, various obscure errors occured in Netbeans itself (in Notifications tab), seemingly halting the whole process of spawning the server instance and deploying the application.

Comment: in NB 15, I got an error building all, but when I went to contrib/j2ee.weblogic9, `ant nbm` did the trick

Comment: in netbeans 17 works fine with weblogic9.nbm file as plugin !!

Answer (score 1):

From what i can tell only Netbeans versions 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0 can work with weblogic as of now. Also the guide you are following is using a pre Apache Netbeans version. I would recommend switching to one of the following Netbeans versions. Download the All bundle or EE.

- [Netbeans 8.0](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.0/)
- [Netbeans 7.4](https://netbeans.org/downloads/7.4/)

https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/web/jsf-jpa-weblogic.html

Comment: Yes, I know it's for another version, but, netbeans should allow me to add the weblogic server

Comment: From what i can tell they seem to indicate its only supported on the above versions

Comment: Is there a way you could try one of the versions above? Or are you locked in to Apache Netbeans 11?

Comment: no, I'm no locked, but I think that a last version IDE is useless if it does not work with other servers. 
On the other hand, many thanks for your response

Comment: personal i prefer the pre Apache Netbeans because majority of the plugins are designed for them and the Apache seemed to lose features. But thats just me. Let me know it it works with the versions above. Hopefuly your other servers will work with it. :).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apache NetBeans 11.0 does not currently support the addition or use of a WebLogic server. See open Apache NetBeans Bug Report 2476: [Netbeans 11 EE Support Weblogic Server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2476)

I don't know for sure, but I suspect that this is a legal problem is related to licensing issues rather than any technical obstacles. The absence of licensing on Apache NetBeans 11.0 also impacts other important products such as Hibernate ([NETBEANS-2719 Resolve Hibernate Support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2719)), and Wildfly ([NETBEANS-2415
Bring back support for WildFly server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2415)).

There are licensing issues because Apache assumed ownership of NetBeans releases from Oracle last year.

Also, because WebLogic was supported "out of the box" in NetBeans 8.2 there is no old WebLogic plugin available for use on Apache NetBeans 11.0.

Your options are:

- Regress NetBeans to use the most recent NetBeans release which does support WebLogic: Oracle NetBeans 8.2. Note that this means you cannot develop using Java EE 8, nor use any JDK version > 8.
- Stick with Apache NetBeans 11.0, and instead of WebLogic use one of the four application servers which it formally supports "out of the box": Payara, Glassfish, Apache Tomcat and Apache TomEE.
- Install your WebLogic server outside of Apache NetBeans 11.0, and deploy your NetBeans web applications to that external server.