# Weblogic Error - Could not initialize class weblogic.jndi.Environment

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, netbeans-10

When I try to debug a `WebApp` configured to run with `Oracle Weblogic Server` from `NetBeans 10`, I always get the following error:

There's not even complicated steps, I just open my project and then `right-click` / `Debug`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.jndi.Environment
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.makeConnection(ClientProviderBase.java:178)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.newJMXConnector(ClientProviderBase.java:84)
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:378)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.WLConnectionSupport$1.call(WLConnectionSupport.java:182)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.WLConnectionSupport.executeAction(WLConnectionSupport.java:112)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.WLConnectionSupport.executeAction(WLConnectionSupport.java:161)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.getTargets(WLDeploymentManager.java:632)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.getTargetMap(ServerInstance.java:560)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.getTargets(ServerInstance.java:518)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerString.getTargets(ServerString.java:117)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerString.toTargets(ServerString.java:155)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.init(TargetServer.java:146)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.undeploy(TargetServer.java:771)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.undeploy(Deployment.java:337)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Undeploy.execute(Undeploy.java:92)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

My environment  is:

- NetBeans 10 running on Java 10.0.2+13
- Windows 10
- Weblogic Server 10.3.6 running on Java 1.6.0.45

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to post this question because it took me the whole morning to find a solution... especially because the most common reason for `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.jndi.Environment` to occur, is when `weblogic.jar` and `wlfullclient.jar` aren't being properly located by any of `IDE`, `WebApp`, or `WL`.

#### To fix the issue just run your project using `NetBeans 8.2`, this seems to be a bug at `NB10` only.

Also, don't even try running it on `NB11`, `NB12`, `NB12.1` nor `NB12.2`. Currently, [Java EE plugin for those versions is discontinued](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2476?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS%20AND%20text%20%7E%20weblogic) so you'll not even be able to add WL to your server list.

The reason it broke in NB10 is that they started removing Java 8 vendor features from it, And the reason it doesn't even is possible to add WL to `NB11 >` is because Oracle removed JDK8 features for the followed releases of Java... [NB integration is not under Apache Licence](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1989) so they just aren't giving support to it now ([is an issue that they refused to fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2476)). However, with a bit of risk, it [can be added manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987800/1657465).

Comment: This is weird since both the calling class in your stacktrace `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory` is in the same jar file as the `weblogic.jndi.Environment`. So there might have been something wrong but I'm not sure this solution is the most common cause. (specifically since I have it too and don't run NB but Eclipse.

Comment: The reason it broke in NB10 is that they started removing Java 8 vendor features from it, I forgot to point that my answer. And the reason it doesn't even is possible to add WL to NB11 > is because of the issue you found when running with JDK11 as Oracle removed JDK8 features for the followed releases of Java...

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse IDE, the solution for me was to switch from JDK11 to JDK8 on the client.